# Run MATLAB in command line allowing display of plots

Tags: matlab, plot, command-line, matlab-figure

To run MATLAB on Linux in the command line I use the following:

```
 matlab -nodisplay
```

But I guess this does not allow windows of plots to open either, because the following command has no output:

```
plot(X,Y)
```

How to allow only graphs and plots to display when running MATLAB from the command line?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Linux, to run MATLAB in a terminal window use the `-nodesktop` option. It causes MATLAB to start without the GUI, with all text input and output to happen through the terminal window. But it does not disable the JVM software altogether and so allows interactive figure windows to be displayed.

The `-nojvm` option disables the JVM software, disallowing all Java-based components of MATLAB, including figure windows. The `-nodisplay` option disables al graphical display output, but doesn't disable the JVM.

For more details, see [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html#buknt9_-3).